# Openshift PHP app throws "404 Page not found error" with custom domain name

Tags: php, domain, alias, http-status-code-404, openshift-online-2

I have a PHP app on Openshift which is working fine with the native URL (e.g `xyz-xy.rhcloud.com`). Later I added an alias to the app(e.g, `www.xyz.com`) and I also updated the CName in my Zone file at godaddy.com. When I enter www.xyz.com, it redirects me to `www.xyz.com/app` and throws a 404 NOT FOUND error. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your custom domain is not setup correctly on your openshift gear in the web console.  Make sure that you added `www.example.com` and not just `example.com`, as we do not automatically accept the `www` if you don't add it to the web console.